# How do I implement cross-correlation to prove two images of the same scene are similar?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

have to do cross-correlation to prove two images-of the same scene and same size- are similar, if someone can help me , I would be grateful.

Comment: Cross correlation **is not** a robust way of calculating the similarity of two images.  Take for example an image which consists of two vertical stripes.  The left half is one colour...say...red, and the right half is another colour...say...blue.  If we had another image that's structured the same, but it having two completely different colours...say...green and yellow, you'd expect the images to be similar because their composition is the same, but cross correlation will consider these as being different.  However, you can use the duplicate post as a start if you really want to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, indeed I am looking to compare similarity between two images which are different in terms of modality, that is to say, an image in RGB, and one in infrared, I wonder if you know a valid similarity metric in this case.